# How to generate number, format "AG-00001" to "AG-99999"?

Tags: node.js

I want to generate number by this format : "AG-00001" -  "AG-99999"(8 characters) Can you help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?, If so, can you also put your code here to check?. If not, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Since your first three characters are "AG-" you can keep them constant and just create random numbers and add them to "AG-".

```
function generate(){
    let str = "AG-";
    for(let x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        str += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    return str;
}

console.log(generate());
```

If you want the generated strings unique, you can just add them to a list or database and check if the string already exists.